# Passing a member function as an argument compile error

Tags: go

I'm modeling the state machine implementation outlined in this talk by Rob Pike https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HxaD_trXwRE&t=1830s
and I'm not able to get it to compile. I've provided a small sample that fails.

The call: m := New(foo)
fails with

```
./main.go:31:11: undefined: foo
```

I've tried

```
      m := New(M.foo)
      m := New(foo(*M))
```

I don't know the proper syntax for this.

```
package main

type StateFunc func(*M) StateFunc

type M struct {
    start StateFunc
}

func New(start StateFunc) *M {
    return &M{
        start: start,
    }
}

func (m *M) foo() StateFunc {
    return nil
}

func (m *M) Start() {
    go m.run()
}

func (m *M) run() {
    state := m.start
    for state != nil {
        state = state(m)
    }
}

func main() {
    m := New(foo)
}
```

I would expect it to compile but I don't know the proper syntax to make this work.

Answer (score 2):

1. the method `(m *M) foo()` doesn't match the signature of `type StateFunc func(*M) StateFunc`
2. `foo` is a method, it has a receiver `*M`, you can't use it without the receiver.

my suggestion is to modify `foo`:

```golang
func foo(*M) StateFunc {
    return nil
}
```